# I am getting an error with urldecode method

Tags: delphi, urldecode

I am getting the following error when decoding url-encoded characters with the `TNetEncoding.URL.Decode()` method:

> No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page

The url parameters are

```
?call=ExportEventPerspectiveAsCSV&min=2020-03-09%2000:00:00&max=2020-03-09%2023:59:59&type=csv&folder=%F6%E7
```

My code:

```pascal
var
  Str: TStringList;
begin
  Str:= TStringList.Create();
  Str.Text := TNetEncoding.URL.Decode(ARequestInfo.QueryParams);// URLDecode(Str.Text);
  Str.Text := StringReplace(Str.Text, '&', #13, [rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```

Comment: What do you expect the given string should decode to? It has [U+F6E7 Private Use Codepoint](https://codepoints.net/U+F6E7) at the end, which causes the error. It's also worth mentioning that you do crazy stuff in your code snippet. You should **first** split the string using `'&'` and **then** decode each URI component to get name-value pairs like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26316106/11562188).

Comment: @PeterWolf `%F6%E7` decodes to U+F6E7 only if it is decoded as UTF-16, which is very unlikely. It is not valid decoded as UTF-8, but it could be valid decoded as another charset. For instance, in ISO-8859-1, it is `öç`. Without knowing which charset originally encoded it, you can't decode it properly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for justification. `TURLEncoding` seems to operate only upon UTF-8. That would mean that OP can't use it for decoding from arbitrary charset or input string is malformed.

Comment: @PeterWolf Indy's `TIdURI.URLDecode()` allows a byte encoding to be specified when decoding URLs

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The OP is using `TNetEncoding.URL.Decode`. Does that use Indy's `TIdURI.URLDecode`?

Comment: @KenWhite No, it does not. `TNetEncoding` is part of Embarcadero's effort to provide their own cross-platform RTL that is not dependent on Indy. `TNetEncoding` is their own implementation for URL, Base64, and HTML encoding/decoding.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That's what I thought, but your comment made it seem like it did - that's why I asked.

Comment: @KenWhite my comment was in reply to Peter's comment to offer an alternative solution, since Indy allows a charset to be specified, whereas `TNetEncoding` does not. Except, now that I look at it, [`TURLEncoding.Decode()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.NetEncoding.TURLEncoding.Decode) does appear to have an optional `AEncoding` parameter that is not present in the base [`TNetEncoding.Decode()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding.Decode)

Comment: I just now noticed the code is using `ARequestInfo.QueryParams`, which implies Indy's `TIdHTTPServer` is being used, so why wouldn't the OP want to use Indy's URL decoder with Indy's server in the first place? `TIdHTTPServer` already handles decoding and splitting the `ARequestInfo.QueryParams` into `ARequestInfo.Params` when `TIdHTTPServer.ParseParams` is True.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `TNetEncoding.URL` decodes an encoded byte sequence as UTF-8, however `%F6%E7` does not represent a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, so it can't be decoded as UTF-8, hence the "no mapping" error.

You need to specify the correct charset encoding (which you will have to figure out what it is meant to be in this situation) in the optional `AEncoding` parameter of [`TURLEncoding.Decode()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.NetEncoding.TURLEncoding.Decode), eg:

```pascal
var
  Str: TStringList;
  Enc: TEncoding;
begin
  Str := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Enc := TEncoding.GetEncoding('TheCharsetHere'); // <-- !!!
    try
      Str.Text := TNetEncoding.URL.Decode(ARequestInfo.QueryParams, [TDecodeOption.PlusAsSpaces], Enc);
    finally
      Enc.Free;
    end;
    Str.Text := StringReplace(Str.Text, '&', #13, [rfReplaceAll]);
  finally
    Str.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That said, you really need to split the value pairs *before* decoding them, not splitting them *after* decoding.  This way, `&` characters encoded as `%26` do not get mistreated, eg:

```pascal
var
  Str: TStringList;
  Enc: TEncoding;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Str := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Enc := TEncoding.GetEncoding('TheCharsetHere'); // <-- !!!
    try
      Str.Delimiter := '&';
      Str.StrictDelimiter := True;
      Str.DelimitedText := ARequestInfo.QueryParams;
      for I := 0 to Str.Count-1 do begin
        Str[I] := TNetEncoding.URL.Decode(Str[I], [TDecodeOption.PlusAsSpaces], Enc);
      end;
    finally
      Enc.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Str.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Just a note that `AEncoding` parameter wasn't available [prior to 10.3 Rio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.NetEncoding.TURLEncoding.Decode). I wasn't able to find release notes mentioning this addition and it comes as no surprise that the optional parameter isn't documented at all so it's easy to overlook or misinterpret its meaning.